# Чем отличается новый объект от this?

Tags: java

Допустим есть такой код:

```
public class Main{
   int a;
   char arr[] = new char[5];
   String word = "";
}
 void foo(){
   Main m = new Main();
   m.a = 5;
}
```

И вот такой:

```
public class Main{
   int a;
   char arr[] = new char[5];
   String word = "";
}
void foo(){
   this.a = 5;
}
```

Чем отличаются эти куски кода ? А именно чем отличается создание объекта от this ?

Comment: this - это обращение к текущему, уже созданному объекту внутри самого объекта, а создание объекта - это новый объект, со своими полями, значениями и проч., никакого отношения не имеющего к другому такому  же объекту. Разница такая же, как между местоимениями (я, мне ..) и фамилией некоторого Петрова

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если только эти фрагменты не являются частью другого, внешнего по отношению к ним класса, то они оба неправильны: метод `foo()` не относится ни к какому классу (а класс `Main` не содержит ни одного метода). Ни один из этих фрагментов не откомпилируеся. Если же предположить, что эти фрагменты являются частями внешнего класса (назовем его `Outer`), то

- В первом фрагменте метод `foo()` класса `Outer` создает новый объект класса `Main` (который при создании инициализирует свои поля `arr` и `word`), присваивает его полю `a` значение 5, но этот новый объект и его поля никак не могут быть использованы, поскольку переменная `m` -- локальная, ее область видимости ограничена методом `foo()`, извне метода она недоступна и при выходе из метода уничтожается.
- Во втором фрагменте метод `foo()` присваивает значение 5 полю `a` объекта класса `Outer`, поскольку метод `foo()` относится к классу `Outer` и в таком методе ключевое слово `this` означает объект, к которому относится метод. Объект класса `Main` во втором фрагменте не создается и соответственно никакие его поля не существуют, не инициализируются и не модифицируются.

Что касается второго вопроса -- отличие `this` от `new` состоит в следующем:

`this` может использоваться в нестатических методах и конструкторах как переменная и в таком случае означает ссылку на существующий (или создаваемый) объект, которому принадлежит метод (иными словами, `"этот объект"`) напр.

```
  void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name; // Присваиваем полю name значение параметра name
  }
```

в коде конструкторов использование `this` в форме вызова метода (`this()`) означает вызов другого конструктора этого же класса, напр.

```
  class MyClass{
    String name;
    int age;
    MyClass(String name) {
      this.name = name; 
    }
    MyClass(String name, int age) {
      this(name); // Вызов первого конструктора
      this.age = age; 
    }
  }
```

`new` -- это всегда создание нового объекта, и совершенно не обязательно объекта того же класса, к которому относится вызывающий метод, напр

```
  ....
  BigDecimal r = new BigDecimal("1234567890123456789.123456789")  
  BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal("3.1415926535897932384626433832795"); 
  BigDecimal square = pi.multiply(r.pow(2)); // Площадь круга
  ....
```

Answer (score 2):

В первом случае Вы внутри foo создаете новый объект класса Main, присваиваете его полю значение 5. Но при выходе из foo этот объект становится доступным для сборки мусора и недоступным извне. А во втором случае Вы просто полю  присваиваете значение 5

Comment: Аааа, то есть мы создали локальный объект и  переменную ?

Comment: да - в данном случае это локальная переменная

Comment: Ок, спасибо !..

Comment: метод `foo()` не относится к классу `Main`, он помещен вне класса.

Comment: это видел - но считаю, что это кусок чего-то большего (не совсем удачное вырезание лишнего из текста кода класса) - потому что иначе бы у человека не скомпилировалось бы ничего, да и IDE бы заругалась